# What is the equivalent of Let Over Lambda in Scala?

Tags: scala, closures, lisp

I am trying to adapt "Land of Lisp" to Scala and I got stuck with the elegant way LISP can support memoization by using the classic Let over Lambda pattern. Here is an example for a counter in Lisp:

```
(let ((count 0))
  (defun add-one ()
    (incf count)))
```

How would this look in scala. I came only up with

```
val addOne = {
   var count = 0
   () => { count = count + 1; count }
}
```

Which I don't find very elegant. Any better proposals?

Comment: Why do you find it less elegant than the Lisp version?

Comment: What Lisp dialect is this? `incf` in Common Lisp (which has no `inc`) already returns the new value. So the function definition reduces to `(defun addone () (incf count))`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Failed to flip between Scala and LISP for the example. It should have been (1+ or (incf))

Comment: Why I do find this less elegant? It's because I have to return a function and use the fact that Scala handles this the same way as a value. So it's very dependent on the way Scala works.